# How Referencing two schema in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

if I have two schemas like: faculty % department how should I connect those two,

I'm getting this error

```
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
```

My files

faculty.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const facultySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    facultyCode: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
      },
      facultyName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
      }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Faculty", facultySchema);
```

departmentSchema.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const departmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    departmentName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
      },
      departmentCode: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
      },
      facultyId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'facultySchema'
      }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Department", departmentSchema);
```

error code form vsCode

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\00-System\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object
    at Function.use (C:\Users\User\Documents\00-System\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\00-System\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (C:\Users\User\Documents\00-System\Backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
C:\Users\User\Documents\00-System\Backend\nod
```

Comment: your schemas look good but the error comes from index.js router.use , show the code of that place

Comment: Hi @Shreyansh Gupta
 do you think it's in my routes

Comment: yes its another problem

Comment: Yes you are correct something wrong with my app.js file.

please find the git hub link here [https://github.com/noorzee/Backedn.git]

Comment: once I comment on these two areas, that error gone.

`// My Routes
app.use("/api", authRoutes); 
app.use("/api", userRoutes);
app.use("/api", facultyRoutes); 
// app.use("/api", departmentRoutes); `
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
------------------------------------

`// My Routes
const authRoutes =  require("./routes/auth");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/user");
const facultyRoutes = require("./routes/faculty");
// const departmentRoutes =  require("./routes/department")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// routes/department.js missing route export 
// type this at the end of the file 

module.exports = router;
```